# Black screen is shown and mobile have to restart when extends Activity

Tags: android

When I extend the `Main.java` by `Activity` it shows a black screen and mobile hang on but when i change it to `FragmentActivity` it works fine, what is the problem here?

Main.java

```
package com.uett.as;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
//import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
//import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

public class Main extends FragmentActivity {

//  MapView map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //  map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    //  map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    //  Touchy t = new Touchy();
    //  List<Overlay> overlayList = map.getOverlays();
    //  overlayList.add(t);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    /*
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    class Touchy extends Overlay{

        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView m){

            return false;

        }
    }
*/
}
```

Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Main" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.uett.as"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.uett.as.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.uett.as.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.uett.as.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="Here is my Key"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can anyone help me to see that what is the problem with this?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a fragment, but your minSdkVersion is 8. Which means you need to use the compatibility library's FragmentActivity to manage the fragment in your layout.

Comment: what changes will be needed if i want to use extends Activity instead of FragmentActivity?

Answer (score 0):

> When I extend the Main.java by Activity it shows a black screen and
>   mobile hang on but when i change it to Fragment Activity it works fine
>   what is the problem here

You have

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

Api level 11 and below you need to use `SupportMapFragment`. So you need to extend `FragmentActivity`. `FragmentActivity` is the base class for support based fragments

Remove

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

You already have

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

There is no need for

```
  <permission
    android:name="com.uett.as.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.uett.as.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

and this

```
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

as of map api v2